# Python application error (Udacity)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been use udacity.com to learn to program an application that allows you to type how old you are and when you hit submit it checks if you typed in the right year, month, and day. Each time I push submit and run it on google app engine the localhost web page it black. Where in my code did I miss up. I check my code and it looks like it should work. I need a second pair of eyes on this.

```
    import webapp2

form="""  
<form method="post">
    What is your birthday?
    <br>
    <label>Month<input type="type" name="month"></label>
    <label>Day<input type="type" name="day"></label>
    <label>Year<input type="type" name="year"></label>
    <div style="color: red">%(error)s</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form> 
"""
def valid_year(year):
        if year and year.isdigit():
            year = int(year)
            if year > 1900 and year < 2020:
                return year

def valid_day(day):
        if day and day.isdigit():
            day = int(day)
            if day > 0 and day <= 31:
                return day

 months = ['Janurary',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']


    month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(),m) for m in months)

def valid_month(month):
        if month:
            short_month =  month[:3].lower()
            return month_abbvs.get(short_month)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()
        self.valid_year(year)
        self.valid_day(day)
        self.valid_month(month)


    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))
        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.write_form("That doesn't look valid to me, friend.")
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: Your inputs should say `type="text"` not `type="type"`.

Answer (score 1):

In method "get", you call methods valid_year(), valid_day(), valid_month(), so:

1) You call it without any arguments, but in method declaration you declared that there is argument valid_year(**year**), valid_day(**day**), valid_month(**month**), so if you calling it without argument, it cause error.

2) I think you "get" method should look like this:

```
def get(self):
    self.write_form()
```

When get method performed you don't receive any arguments/data, so there nothing to validate.

Comment: I correct it ,but i keep on getting a blank page each time i try to run it. I add the new code at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined method post as below:
  def post(self):
But when you are opening the tag form  you have not defined method="post".
Add method="post" to your form tag.

Comment: Just before the line "What is your birthday?"

Comment: I correct it ,but i keep on getting a blank page each time i try to run it. I add the new code at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code verbatim and I get the following error which causes the blank screen.

```
ERROR    2015-08-18 21:27:32,377 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/Josh/main.py", line 1
    import webapp2
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

In python, whitespace matters. It seems you have some inconsistent indentation with your initial `import webapp2` as well as `month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(),m) for m in months)`.